# Create app with SSLSocket Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, jsse

I want to create an app use `SSLSocket`: client send a `String` to server and server will uppercase that `String` and send back to client for display.

### SSLServer

```
public class SSLServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        try{
        //Creaet a SSLServersocket
        SSLServerSocketFactory factory=(SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket sslserversocket=(SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(1234);
        //Tạo 1 đối tượng Socket từ serversocket để lắng nghe và chấp nhận kết nối từ client
        SSLSocket sslsocket=(SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
        //Tao cac luong de nhan va gui du lieu cua client
        DataInputStream is=new DataInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
        PrintStream os=new PrintStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
        while(true)  //khi dang ket noi voi client
        {
            //Doc du lieu den
            String input=is.readUTF();
            String ketqua=input.toUpperCase();
            //Du lieu tra ve
            os.println(ketqua);
        }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
           System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

### SSLClient

```
public class SSLClient {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
        //Mo 1 client socket den server voi so cong va dia chi xac dinh
        SSLSocketFactory factory=(SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslsocket=(SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("127.0.0.1",1234);

        //Tao luong nhan va gui du lieu len server
        DataOutputStream os=new DataOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream is=new DataInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());

        //Gui du lieu len server
        String str="helloworld";
        os.writeBytes(str);

        //Nhan du lieu da qua xu li tu server ve
        String responseStr;
        if((responseStr=is.readUTF())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(responseStr);
        }

        os.close();
        is.close();
        sslsocket.close();
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When run `SSLServer`. It displays this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds 
    to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled
```

I have search and do some ways but.. Can you help me.

Comment: server at startup gives you that exception? on which line? have you googled for that error?

Comment: These examples will help you. You will need correct SSL certificate in keystore.
[example 1](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=867)
[example 2](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=853)

Comment: I've seen those: https://github.com/gpotter2/SSLKeystoreFactories which are 2 classes that ease the creation of SSL sockets. It's quite old but still working

Answer (score 13):

This will generate certificate:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore yourKEYSTORE -keyalg RSA
```

Enter yourPASSWORD and than start your server with ssl debug information(put yourKEYSTORE into directory with SSLServer.class):

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=yourKEYSTORE -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=yourPASSWORD -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol -Djavax.net.debug=ssl SSLServer
```

Than start your client(put yourKEYSTORE into directory with SSLClient.class):

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=yourKEYSTORE -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yourPASSWORD SSLClient
```

Answer (score 2):

[@corVaroxid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283970/5318303) is right. But if you want to set configurations programmatically *to **avoid global settings*** (like me), you can go like below (**Kotlin**):

```kotlin
val password = "yourPassword".toCharArray()

val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(File("yourKeystorePath.jks"), password)

val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)

val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("NewSunX509")
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password)

val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS") //"SSL" "TLS"
context.init(keyManagerFactory.keyManagers, trustManagerFactory.trustManagers, null)

val factory = context.serverSocketFactory

(factory.createServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT) as SSLServerSocket).use { serverSocket ->
    logger.trace("Listening on port: $LISTENING_PORT")

    // ...
}
```

Or in **Java**:

```
final char[] password = "yourPassword".toCharArray();

final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(new File("yourKeystorePath.jks"), password);

final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("NewSunX509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);

final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");//"SSL" "TLS"
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

final SSLServerSocketFactory factory = context.getServerSocketFactory();

try (SSLServerSocket serverSocket = ((SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT))) { 
    logger.trace("Listening on port: " + LISTENING_PORT);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the certificates that you have installed. Make sure they are supporting the cipher suites that you are negotiating.