# Security For android/javaI

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl

I am about to start a contract with a company and they need their data which I will be sending via sockets to be securely transferred from their Android device to a Java server.
To do so I am going to put data from a form into an XML document, cypher it, then send it over the internet to a cloud server through Sockets.

My question: What is the most secure way to use Sockets to send data?
I've found `SSLSocketFactory` but I don't really understand what it's doing and seings though I have little experience in security I was wondering..

Is `SSLSocketFactory` the proper aproach? Is there a better way to have a secure connection between a client and a host over a socket?

Comment: The Android developer guide for securing HTTP connections is thorough about what you require. Read this [link]http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html[link] for understanding and implementing it according to your requirements.

Comment: I'm not using HTTP I am using Sockets
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: Is my understanding that SSL is the appropriate way to perform secure information exchange, it based in public key sharing and if you don't want to use Web Services I would use SSL too.

Comment: any good tutorials related to sockets? All I can find is ones for HTTP :(

Comment: BTW Secure Sockets Layer = SSL, HTTPS (use for secure HTTP connection) works over SSL, so I will take I look to the link suggested by @cyber_rookie , Good luck!

Comment: From my understanding (could be wrong) SSL is used to stop the connection from being able to be read during transit... Through using a cipher, am I doing so? Also, is this ssl for sockets? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874387/create-app-with-sslsocket-java :\ I know the question is dumb.. Just never have done security in programming and I'm trying to avoid the use of HTTP