# How to handle SSL Handshake

Tags: java, ssl, serversocket, handshake

Im using the below code and trying to access it via browser using https://localhost:32567?test=aaa

```
   SSLServerSocketFactory sslContextFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
   SSLServerSocket ssl = (SSLServerSocket) sslContextFactory.createServerSocket(32567);     
   ssl.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "SSLv3"});
   ssl.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslContextFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites());

   Arrays.stream(ssl.getEnabledCipherSuites()).forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));

   SSLSocket clientSocket = null;
   while ((clientSocket = (SSLSocket) ssl.accept()) != null) {
       System.out.println("--------------------------");
       System.out.println("--= SSL REQUEST ---");

       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
       byte[] messageByte = new byte[1000];
       messageByte[0] = in.readByte();
       messageByte[1] = in.readByte();
    }
```

Im getting the below error

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

The ciphers listed are

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5

Comment: Did you already checked this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/15144731/4506285

Comment: Try enabling SSL debugging to get more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659564/limiting-java-ssl-debug-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it cause i did not have a certificate created

[Create app with SSLSocket Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874387/create-app-with-sslsocket-java)

keytool -genkey -keystore yourKEYSTORE -keyalg RSA
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore yourKEYSTORE -destkeystore yourKEYSTORE -deststoretype pkcs12

and use java options

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=yourKEYSTORE -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=test1234 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol